# Is the factor group abelian if subgroup is normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am just wondering if N is normal subgroup of G, then G/N  is abelian.

And if this is true, does it follow that if (G:H)=2, then G/H is abelian?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is false. Take $G=S_3$ and $N=1$.

The second one is true because $(G:H)=2$ implies that $H$ normal and that $G/H$ has order $2$. Every group of order $2$ is cyclic and so abelian.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add that  $G/N$ is abelian if and only if $N$ contains the derived subgroup, i.e. the subgroup generated by the *commutators* $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.